# Regex not working in asp.net(.aspx page)

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a regex thats working normally (when i tried through online regex checking websitesites).
This should not allow 1234.1234.1234.1234 but while I am using it in asp.net,it is allowing even those values.

Any suggestion?

```
var ipfilter = new RegExp("(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?$)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET regex differs from JavaScript one *immensely*. However, in this case, it is a regular problem: the dot must be preceded with a *literal* backslash, or placed inside a character class. I suggest the latter as it is less error-prone, and you need to add a `^` (start of string) anchor:

```
var rx = "^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?$)";
```

Comment: Thanks ..You are genius.

Answer (score 1):

Is the online regex checking website you used testing regex for .NET? .NET regex differs slightly from Javascript regex.

https://regex101.com/ - you can test against .NET on this by selecting .NET from the flavor options on the left.